# How can I get the Luna theme in elementary OS Freya?

Tags: elementary-os, theme

Is there a way to get the elementary OS Luna theme in Freya?
I don't want to get rid of stuff like the header bar, I just want that blue theme.

Also, can I set wingpanel to the be translucent all the time instead of it automatically becoming opaque on maximize?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To answer the first part of your question: You can't. Luna's theme was built for a specific older version of Gtk. The version of Gtk shipped in Freya is not compatible with this older theme. It will not work.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question - the only way you can do this is if you take the theme from Luna and port it over manually. :/

However, to disable autochanging on Freya, go to dconf editor, then open `org`>`pantheon`>`desktop`>`wingpanel`and you should see `auto-adjust-alpha` ticked. Untick that and change `background-alpha` to be `0`.